# Hello world example is not working

Tags: java, android

I am following a tutorial for beginners with Android Studio, and there is a "Hello World" example like this one:

```
package com.example.moi.scaleguess;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView text = new TextView(this);

        text.setText("Hello, you owe me 1 000 000€.");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

But when I am starting this app either on my phone or on a virtual one, I only get "Hello World !" message AND NOT "Hello, you owe me 1 000 000€.".

I don't understand, it's like another program is started.

Comment: You have created object of `TextView` at runtime and you are not adding it to any view. so it will not be visible, you have to first add it to any view by calling `view.addView(text)` if you want to create it at runtime, or do as answered by Zarul Izham

Comment: @Prashant thank you, but how do I create a view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a Java View object and then you tell Android to print a XML view with **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** on screen so that is what it does.
I you want to use Java object only you should try this code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView text = new TextView(this);

    text.setText("Hello, you owe me 1 000 000€.");

    setContentView(text);
}
```

Or you can use XML for instanciate a Java View object, and then change the text as Zarul Izham and Vyacheslav advice you to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your initialization of `TextView` is wrong. Here is the example:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId); // must be tally in your activity_main layout.
```

You need to cast the view in layout (XML file) into `TextView`.

Another one is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` must be called before initializing any view.

Your `onCreate` function must be look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    text.setText("Hello, you owe me 1 000 000€.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewIdInXMLFile);

        text.setText("Hello, you owe me 1 000 000€.");
    }
}
```